# Significance of gl/gG rating on circuit breaker

Tags: protection

I noticed that circuit breakers have a gl/gG rating. eg: gl/gG= 100A. Can someone explain the significance of this rating?

Comment: I believe that gG is used for fuses only, and not for circuit breakers. Circuit breakers have a different kind of characteristics, of which type "C" is the most common. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be covered by IEC 60269.
gG and gL is the same thing where gL is an older definintion.

Quote From [Wikipedia article about IEC 60269](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60269)

> The application cateogory is a two-digit code.
>       The first letter is **a** if the fuse is for short-circuit protection only; an associated device must provide overload protection.
>       The first letter is **g** if the fuse is intended to operate even with currents as low as those that cause it to blow in one hour. These are considered general-purpose fuses for protection of wires.
>
> The second letter indicates the type of equipment or system to be protected:

```
D – North American time-delay fuses for motor circuits, UL 248 fuses
G – General purpose protection of wires and cables
M – Motors
N – Conductors sized to North American practice, UL 248 fuses
PV – Solar photovoltaic arrays as per 60269-6
R, S – Rectifiers or semiconductors as per 60269-5
Tr – Transformers[citation needed]
```

> Any fuses built to the IEC 60269 standard and carrying the same application category (for example, gG or aM) will have similar electrical characteristics, time-current characteristics, and power dissipation as any other, even if the fuses are made in the packages standardized to the earlier national standards.

Unquote.

The gG/gL 100A that is mentioned in the question should be the fuse current rating. The current that a fuse in series with the device can continously pass through without opening.

According to the comment below, the device marked with gG/gL is a Motor Starter Protector (MSP). This should be put in series with a fuse that won't trip unless a short circuit fault occurs. Not even a stalled motor should trip it. Have a look at Rockwell Automations has a paper "193-2.10: A Guide to Understanding: Short-Circuit Protection" which deals with this. There is mentioned that the fuse should handle approx. 6 to 8 times the Full Load Current. This corresponds quite well to the MSP mentioned in the question.

Here is a picture of how the MSP and Fuse works together:
[image]

Comment: The only issue is that it doesn't make sense for this controller  to be rated at 60A. This is the [device](https://mall.industry.siemens.com/DatasheetService/DatasheetService?control=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%3Cpdf_generator_control%3E%3Cmode%3EPDF%3C%2Fmode%3E%3Cpdmsystem%3EPMD%3C%2Fpdmsystem%3E%3Ctemplate_selection+mlfb%3D%223RV1021-1KA10%22+system%3D%22PRODIS%22%2F%3E%3Clanguage%3Een%3C%2Flanguage%3E%3Ccaller%3EMall%3C%2Fcaller%3E%3C%2Fpdf_generator_control%3E) I'm talking about. Its should open at 9-12.5A, so  gG/gL of 60A doesn't make sense.

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Comment: Another term often used in conjunction with gL/gG is "fast acting", see page 1, second column, first paragraph of https://rexel-cdn.com/Products/Littelfuse/DZ16F25.pdf?i=D03B0BA1-AE11-47D7-9F34-D54F6F1299A7

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.profuseinternational.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/ProFuse-Fuse-School-Module-2.pdf): gL/gG class fuses are general purpose and rated for 1000V or less.

[image: http://www.profuseinternational.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/ProFuse-Fuse-School-Module-2.pdf]

Comment: The only issue is that this gG/gL rating has a current associated to it. eg gG/gL = 60amps. What does this current mean?. Its not the CB's current rating because this is different (in my case 9.5-15 amps)

Comment: I believe that would be the maximum breaking capacity, so there should be a fuse in series no larger than that.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany "this" url https://www.profuseinternational.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/ProFuse-Fuse-School-Module-2.pdf is no longer available.